# Creating a variable from a large, complicated section of HTML

Tags: php

I have several large (200+ lines) of HTML that I need to place in a variable to use several times in a loop.  It gets very messy to escape this and that and keep formatting clean.  Is there a way to set a variable like this *if* statement?

```
<?php if($condition): ?> <p>html here</p> <?php endif; ?>
```

I know it’s possible with external files, but I’d rather not add a series of includes to achieve this.

Comment: *Is there anyway to set a variable like this IF statement?* What exactly do you mean by that? Please clarify (`if` statements are not *set* like you set a variable).

Comment: Notice the way the php wraps around the html so that no special formatting is required.

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion.  The point of my question has NOTHING to do with "if statments" but the FORMAT of the above if statement and the way the php wraps around the html.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) notation:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="section">
    <h2>Header</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>
HTML;
```

No worrying about special characters, and you can reuse the variable as much as you want.

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  Thanks.  I've never heard of this before today.  Is it in any way a bad practice or hard on performance?

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces just like you normally would.

```
<?php if($condition) { ?> <p>html here</p> <?php } ?>
```

This also works for loops and such

```
<?php foreach($results as $record) { ?> 
  <p>html <?php echo $record['title']; ?>here</p> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Take a look here: "[Embedding PHP in HTML](http://openp2p.com/pub/a/php/2001/05/03/php_foundations.html)"

```
<?php if(conditions): ?>
... HTML CODE ...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to assign the HTML to a variable for whatever reason, also consider using a heredoc or nowdoc http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0):

This is an extreme solution but if I understand your question correctly, you could use output buffering.

```
<?php ob_start(); if($condition): ?> <p>html here</p> <?php endif; $var = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Although I wouldn't recommend storing huge blocks of test in a variable.

Comment: In what way is it extreme? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

To get the HTML in a variable you can simply use one of the below codes

Reference [Output Buffering Control](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

```html
<?php
    ob_start();
?>
<!-- your stuff here -->
<div class="main-div">
    <p class='text'>html here</p>
    <p class='text'>html here</p>
    <p>html here</p>
</div>

<?php
    $output = ob_get_clean(); // HTML to variable
    // Do something with output
?>
```

OR

Reference [Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

```html
<?php
$html = <<<EOD
<div class="main-div">
    <p class='text'>html here</p>
    <p class='text'>html here</p>
    <p>html here</p>
</div>
EDO;
?>
```